# Windows firewall - Predefined set of computers

Tags: windows, networking, firewall

In the built-in firewall for Windows (Windows Firewall with Advanced Security), the definition of a firewall rule includes a Scope, which is a set of IP address filters which apply to the rule.  There are three basic possibilities:  IP Address/Subnet, IP address range, and **Predefined set of computers**.  The first two are self explanatory.

If the Predefined Set option is selected, there are several choices:  "Default Gateway", "WINS Servers", "DHCP Servers", "DNS Servers", "Local subnet", "Intranet", "Remote Corp Network", "Internet", "Play To Renderers".

So, my question is about these "predefined" options.  I cannot find any definitive documentation which describes what these actually are.  Some of them are, again, self explanatory (like "Local Subnet"), but others are mysterious (like "Play To Renderers").  And even the more obvious ones could have subtle permutations (what if there are multiple subnets?).

Where is there documentation (ideally from Microsoft) which describes **all** these "predefined" options?  A nice extra would be documentation for a way to add something to this list (even using something esoteric like a plugin or custom DLL).

Comment: Short answer: you can't define a "set" yourself. Also: I never found a documentation either. Check [this serverfault thread](http://serverfault.com/questions/773529/predefined-set-of-computers-where-to-define).

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to find any Microsoft documentation detailing what exactly these predefined options refer to. It appears no such documentation exists as [even on the TechNet forums no one was able to locate it](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4d2e4cce-ebc2-433c-8c7c-3e1bc5376471/windows-firewall-internet-and-intranet-predefined-set-of-computers?forum=winserversecurity).